# Trigger before insert

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2000, sql-insert

A legacy app sends a sql insert query with a date using the spanish format (dd-mm-yyyy)
I need to change that to english format (mm-dd-yyyy) using a trigger before insert.
How I do this? My database is SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a trigger, consider just changing the Language property of the Login used by the application to one with the proper locale.

[image]

Example:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH
-- Query:
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '9/6/91')
-- Result: 
-- 1991-09-06 00:00:00.000
GO

SET LANGUAGE SPANISH
-- Query:
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '9/6/91')
-- Result:
-- 1991-06-09 00:00:00.000
```

---

**Edit:** For SQL Server 2000, see the [BOL Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196707%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for configuration.  The LANGUAGE option can [also be set in ODBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224753%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry but I can't change the config, I need a solution using trigger.

Comment: @sebagiar, the closest you can come is an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx), but you don't get to change the datatype at that point.  The conversion from `varchar` to `datetime` will have already happened, and you will overflow the month with any day past 12.

Comment: @sebagiar, I suppose you could create a view with the same name as the old table, swap the `datetime` column for `varchar`, `SET DATEFORMAT mdy`, then cast from `varchar` to `datetime`... but yuck.  Is there a reason you cannot change configuration?  There are many places to change it...